# How to run multiple browser sessions (parallel execution) with Selenium + TestNG using @BeforeSuite annotation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I can run multiple Chrome browser sessions **without** `@BeforeSuite` annotation , but sometimes I need to assign some variables or do something in `@BeforeSuite` before going to `@BeforeClass` and `@BeforeTest` , and the same time I need to start multiple browsers session parallel.  How can I do that ?

This is a simplified example of my codes where I use `@BeforeSuite` to assigned some variables and then calling 2 parallel tests from `TestNG.xml`  . It will only call 1 test (not 2).

But if I don't use `@BeforeSuite` , it will work perfectly fine (2 tests will run parallel).

Is it possible to run parallel tests and at the same time still using `@BeforeSuite` ?  Sometimes we do need to use `@BeforeSuite` in some test scenarios and call multiple browsers sessions.

Thank You.

```java
public class MyClass {
  String baseURL;
  String browser;

  @BeforeSuite
  private void setTheVariables() {
    //Some codes here
    //Some codes here
    this.browser = "chrome";
  }


  @BeforeClass
  private void myBeforeClass() {
    //Some codes here
    //Some codes here
  }


  @BeforeTest
  private void myBeforeClass() {
    //Some codes here
    //Some codes here
  }


  @Test
  @Parameters("baseURL")
  public void f(String baseURL) {

    if (this.browser == "chrome") {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\\\Selenium\\\\chromedriver.exe");
      DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
      LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
      logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
      caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
      System.out.println("I am going to " + baseURL);
      driver.get(baseURL);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `testNG.xml` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="TestSuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">



  <test name="Test1" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="baseURL" value="http://www.amazon.com" />

    <classes>
      <class name="package.myClass" />
    </classes>
  </test>



  <test name="Test2" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="baseURL" value="http://www.google.com" />

    <classes>
      <class name="package.myClass" />
    </classes>

  </test>



</suite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Beforesuite** annotated method run before testNG XML. So you have to use another annotation just below this order i.e. ***BeforeClass*** annotation for setting the browser type in your java class.    Add a parameter named **browser** in your testNG xml to pass on the type of browser. That shall make the parallel execution possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="TestSuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
  <test name="Test1" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="baseURL" value="http://www.amazon.com" />
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome">
    <classes>
      <class name="package.myClass" />
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Test2" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="baseURL" value="http://www.google.com" />
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox">
    <classes>
      <class name="package.myClass" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass by Browser value in .xml file, instead of passing it in Java class file, and execution can be handle through .java file.

Example:
   `<parameter name="myBrowser" value="firefox"/>    
    <parameter name="myBrowser" value="chrome"/>`
       
and it can implement wherever its preferable,  Before Suite/Class/Test/Method

```
@Parameters("parameter name")
@BeforeTest 
public void xyz(String myBrowser) throws MalformedURLException {
    if (myBrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpathofchrome);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (myBrowser.equals("firefox")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverpathoffirefox);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```